# trying to find cardinal number of an input in js

Tags: javascript, html

i have tryed to say

if (input.length < 8) {ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤalert("Your password should have more than 8 characters")ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ}ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤelseㅤ{ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ  ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤreturnㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ}

but when i click on submit it just gives me an alert when my input is more than 8 characters pls help

```js
/*function show(){
   //alert("hi")
  var input = document.getElementById("input")
  var noeye = document.getElementById("noeye")
  var eye = document.getElementById("eye")
  if(input.type == "password" ){
   input.type = "text"
   noeye.hidden = null
   eye.hidden = true
  }
  else {
   input.type = "password"
  }
}

function hide(){
  var input = document.getElementById("input")
  var noeye = document.getElementById("noeye")
  var eye = document.getElementById("eye")
  if(input.type == "text" ){
   input.type = "password"
   noeye.hidden = true
   eye.hidden = null
}
  else {
   input.type = "text"
  }
}*/

function error(){
   var btn = document.getElementById("submit")
   var input = document.getElementById("input")

   if(input.length < 8){
     alert("Your password should have more than 8 characters")
   }
   else{
      return
   }
   
}
```

```css
body {
   background-image: url(https://worldstrides.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/iStock_000040849990_Large.jpg);
    background-size: fill;
}

.form-box {
    position: relative;
    border: 25%;
    top: 250px;
    left: 35%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: black;
}

.email-box {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    top: 2%;
}

.password-box {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    top: 27%;
}

.email-box input{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid grey;
    width: 59%;
}

.password-box input{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid grey;
    width: 59%;
}

.envelope{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
}

.key{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
}

#noeye{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
}

#eye{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
}

#submit {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 70%;
    width: 65%;
    color: grey;
}

.submit button {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border:2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <title>Youssef's Website</title>
    <script src="3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
    <div class="form-box" >

        <h2  style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 37%; position: relative; " >Login Here</h2>
       
        <div class="password-box">
            <img class="key" src="2.png">
            <input id="input" style="position: relative;" type="password" placeholder="Type your password" maxlength="8" required>
            <img id="noeye" src="noeye.png" hidden onclick="hide()" >
            <img id="eye" src="eye.png" onclick="show()" >
        </div>
        
        <div class="submit" >
            <button onclick="error()" id="submit"  type="button">Submit </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="email-box">
            <img class="envelope" src="1.png">
            <input style="position: relative;" type="email" placeholder="Type your email">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

strong text

Comment: try replacing `input.length` with `input.value.length`

Comment: Add a `return false;` after the alert to cancel the event

Comment: You test for a length less than 8 (7 or below) and ask for a password with "more than 8 characters". This error message doesn't match your code's expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("theInput").value (value is missing)

Quick done for the length...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
    function handle()
{
    let input = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let len = input.length;
    if(len>=8){
        alert("submit the form of " + len + " characters" )
        // add Your code to submit the form (here nothing is send).
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("do NOT submit the form of " + len + " characters" );
        return false; //do not submit the form
    } 
}
   </script>    
<title>Input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form_container">
        <!-- complete the form with your action... -->
        <form id="myform" onsubmit="return handle()">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
            <button type="submit">Post it</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```